# Use rediect 301 to remove folder from URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, woocommerce

I have a web site on woocommerce with Sahifa theme, I don't why they're a lot of link with 404 error, like those:

/categoria-prodotto/aromi/**feed**/page/10/?orderby=date

/categoria-prodotto/accessori/**feed**/page/2/

I want remove /feed/ folder (I don't use feed) and reciderct on the same URL without /feed/ folder.

For example:

/categoria-prodotto/accessori/feed/page/2/

To

/categoria-prodotto/accessori/page/2/

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this code** 
by pasting it in your `functions.php` file

```
function na_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( 'feed' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
        return $post_link;
    }

    $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );

    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'na_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function na_parse_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'feed', 'page' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'na_parse_request' );
```

After paste this code, You need to **update your permalinks.** This function is basically remove that slug from all of your urls

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answer, but i'd like remove **/feed/** and put **redirect 301** on link without **/feed/**

Thanks